# How to Create a CAPTCHA enabled Custom Google Drive Form

Tags: google-drive, spam-prevention, captcha

I don't have much knowledge of coding. How can I create Google Form with CAPTCHA to avoid spamming. Any form of CAPTCHA will work.

Comment: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/MiS-ZqNYQNU

Answer (score 1):

> You can create your own simple CAPTCHA by inserting a multiple choice
>   question like this:
>
> How much is three plus seven?
>
> ( ) Don't know    ( ) 9      ( ) 10      ( ) 11
>
> Use the "Go to page based on answer" option to jump back to the page
>   where the CAPTCHA is, or to the next page in the event the humanoid
>   filling the form gets it right. That should let you avoid most bots.

As posted on [Google Product forum](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/MiS-ZqNYQNU/G8wlMFBNXZgJ)